# WinEventLog for monitoring BitLocker

Tags: windows, bitlocker, event-log, splunk

I am a Newbie to Splunk and working on monitoring the BitLocker process. I wondered if I could leverage any Windows Security logs to check whether the BitLocker was enabled by someone to encrypt files or disks. Also, I wanted to monitor if anyone deleted the BitLocker Recovery key on ActiveDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the MSDN article on [BitLocker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/protect/tech-ref/bitlocker/about-event-logs)

Then go to

- [Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/protect/tech-ref/bitlocker/server-event-logs) logs
- [Client](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/protect/tech-ref/bitlocker/client-event-logs) logs

What do you want to collect? Why? How do you intend to use them?